# Is it appropriate to ask a question on EL&U directed at a single user?

Tags: discussion

*What's the origin of "narf-farbling"?*

So I came across this word on a [separate meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/nobody-cares-how-you-pronounce-it#comment23302_6603), and LOVED it, having never heard it before.  So I googled:

[Two](http://w3facility.org/question/what-is-it-called-when-you-%E2%80%9Crefill%E2%80%9D-a-debit-card/). [results](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6603/nobody-cares-how-you-pronounce-it).

One of which being the page I just came from.  Both from a user with the handle *Marthaª*.  What a coinkidink.

So while I'm still absolutely curious where Martha came up with *narf-farbling*, the more *meta* question is, **is it appropriate to ask a question on EL&U directed at a single user?**

Comment: You could ask them on chat, but otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

Etiquette suggests that it is not appropriate to name users, but it depends on a case-by-case basis. Generally speaking, I would avoid doing so unless you wanted to compliment the person, which you've done in this case. :)

Concerning *narf-farbling* it's not necessary to name the person but you might want to add a link directing users to how the word is used, which will make it counter-productive!

Who would benefit from the question? If there are only two results for *narf-farbling* how could users possibly contribute with their "answers"?

What would your question be? Would you ask about its origins? Then you need to ask its creator! Would you ask for people's opinions as to whether we should adopt this expression in our everyday lives, then the question will be closed as being primarily opinion-based aka, POB.

One way your question could be on topic would be to (1.) ask about the origins of "narf" and "farbling" (2.) ask for other similar compounds with either *narf* or *farble*.

However, I don't see how a post asking about a specific (and such a unique) neologism could generate quality answers. But you could try looking at [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neologisms) tagged `neologism` for ideas.

Comment: +1 thx for your very good suggestions re: neologisms. but the general question mostly remains. (although: this might be the only case in which it applies.)

Comment: also, i've updated the title appropriately.

Comment: I see the *only* two instances of the usage are from the same person, but that I as a native speaker had no problem inferring the intended meaning *(generic term for "performing complex activity, fiddling about", etc.)*. So I thought I'd try inventing one of my own. My first attempt, [***flob-dobbing,***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22flob-dobbing%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl) turns out to have been used ***twice*** already! Google really does index just about *everything!* :)